# Python, opening and writing in .txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting this error message:

> io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable

from this code:

```
f=open('namn.txt', 'w')
namnnr=1
for rad in f.readlines():
    print(str(namnnr)+namnnr)
    namnnr+=1
    f.close()
```

Why is that the case?

Answer (score 8):

You're passing 'w' as the file open mode. 'w' means 'write'. Use 'r' for 'read'.